# Store monolog into database?

Tags: symfony5, monolog

I need to log all the user activities into the DB, So I think of storing the Monolog into database.

So far, I have done following:

### monolog.yaml

```
monolog:
    channels: ['db']
    handlers:
        db:
            channels: ['db']
            type: service
            id: monolog.db_handler
```

### services.yaml

```
services:
    ...
    ...

    monolog.db_handler:
        class: App\Service\MonologDBHandler
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

### MonologDBHandler.php

```
use App\Entity\Log;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler;

class MonologDBHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    public function __construct(private readonly EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function write(array $record): void
    {
        $logEntry = new Log();
        $logEntry->setContext($record['context']);

        $this->em->persist($logEntry);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

Now inside my controller,

```
$this->logger->info('something happened');
```

I do not see any insert into my database. Can anybody please assist me ?

Answer (score -1):

According to this [example](https://gist.github.com/alejobit/adad4c846b34cc93a77f5dd89334fafc), you need to tell to your logger that you are logging to the **'db'** that you've created so `$this->logger->info('something happened');` would turn into `$this->logger->info('db', 'something happened');`. Indeed, your handler is not triggered by all events, only the ones tagged with **'db'**.

If you want more informations about the channels you can check them [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/channels_handlers.html#yaml-specification).

I hope it will help you.